# sub-directory dependencies in CMake

Tags: c, cmake, sdl, sdl-2

I am working on a chip8 emulator in C and I am using CMake to handle the compilation and linking of libraries in my project.

my working directory looks like this

```
build > 
cmake >
   FindSDL2.cmake
library > 
   SDL2
      bin >
      include >
      lib >
      share >
src > 
   Chip8 >
       Chip8.c
   Disassembler >
       Disassembler.c
   Display >
       Display.c
   main.c
CMakeLists.txt
```

this is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(chip_8 VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/library/SDL2/)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

add_executable(chip_8 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.c)

target_include_directories(chip_8 PUBLIC ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(chip_8 ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

My display.c requires the SDL2 library. While I could just put all the executables in the add_executable, but that would mean I would also get to include SDL.h in all of the c files, which I don't want I only want to include in the display.h. The above CMakeLists.txt was made when I wanted to add the SDL2 library locally in the project directory, instead of it sitting in the system files of mingw (the bin, include and lib folders of mingw).

How do I change the structure of my project or the CMakeLists.txt so that I can include SDL2 in the display.c in the Display sub-directory

Comment: "that would mean I would also get to include SDL.h in all of the c files, which I don't want I only want to include in the display.h." - No one forces a C file to `#include` a header which is not used by this source file. Could you show the exact error message if you omit that `#include`? "How do I change the structure of my project or the CMakeLists.txt so that I can include SDL2 in the display.c in the Display sub-directory" -  Just link the library/executable, which contains the source `display.c`, with SDL2 library in the same way, as you link `chip_8` in your current code.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, there is one forcing me to include SDL. So i might just add all the source files in one src directory and add them via add executable function